# SQL QUERY-create column in that query

Tags: sql, t-sql

Hi everyone I was wondering if its possible to create a new column in a SELECT query?

I currently have a query that pulls in data for Part numbers, their carrier number, their carrier state, and the end use for them. I want to add one more column to the query, name it 'eligibility' and the values would be

- "C" if the end use of that part = certification and it exists in this other table in the database. *So if the part's end use is cert and it exists in that other table (named special programs) than it would be "C" in this new field*
- otherwise it would be blank. Is that possible?

The SELECT Statement:

```
Select distinct 
    pn.PNumber, 
    ht.CarrierID AS 'Carrier Number', 
    chs.CarrierDescriptionText AS 'Carrier State', 
    ct.EndUsedName AS 'End Use'
```

Results example:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [`CASE...WHEN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.120).aspx) and [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336(v=sql.120).aspx).

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals, use double quotes for identifiers (e.g. "Carrier Number".)

Comment: @X.L.Ant but will that create an extra column?

Comment: It will create a new column in your select output:`CASE WHEN someCol = 'certification' AND EXISTS (SELECT whatever) THEN 'C' ELSE NULL END as yourNewCol. If you want to add a column to your table, you have to `ALTER` the table, add a column and populate it.

Answer (score 0):

total air code.  The LEFT JOIN relates your_table to other_table, and in the CASE block the ot.?? tests if that related row exists in the other table.  Change your_table, other_table, and ?? to suit your situation.

```html
Select distinct 
    pn.PNumber, 
    ht.CarrierID AS 'Carrier Number', 
    chs.CarrierDescriptionText AS 'Carrier State', 
    ct.EndUsedName AS 'End Use', 
    CASE WHEN [End Use] = 'Certification' AND ot.?? IS NOT NULL THEN 'C' ELSE '' END as eligibility
FROM your_table yt
   LEFT JOIN other_table ot ON yt.?? = ot.??
```

Comment: omg this works perfectly thank you! one last question if you dont mind is there anyway I can reference the whole table like ot.* because it wont let me do that when I change it

Comment: 'I can reference the whole table like ot.*'    Yes, but that will not work if yt and ot have columns with exactly the same name.  If that's the case you'll have to type out all columns.